# How to set bitmap programatically as custom sliding part (pointer) on seek bar?

Tags: android

I need to put on seekbar custom images, problem is that I have image for sliding part but I need in code to fetch from server some number (any integer number ) and need to draw that number on image (used for sliding part). How to change sliding part  (pointer) of seek bar in program, set bitmap as background ?

Comment: use setProgressDrawable(Drawable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sliding part" is called the **thumb**.

To change the thumb:

```
mySeekBar.setThumb(drawable);
```

[SeekBar Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumb%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)